# update startDate / endDate of an existing event (not eventSeries!)

Tags: events, google-apps-script

Is it possible to get a single event by id (and not only an eventSeries with getEventSeriesById())?
I want to update the start- and end-date of a single event and would need something like "getEventById" (which in fact does not exist) - otherwise I have to set a recurrence in an eventseries:

```
var oldEvent = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('...').getEventSeriesById('...');
var recur = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addDailyRule().times(1);
oldEvent.setRecurrence(recur, new Date(2015,0,2), new Date(2015,0,3));
```

I do not want to have recurrent Events in my Calendar, even if they only occur once. Is there another option?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to get a single event by id (and not only an eventSeries with getEventSeriesById())?

Yes, with the [Advanced Calendar Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/calendar). (The result will be an [Events Resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#resource), not a GAS [CalendarEvent](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#), so you'll handle it differently.)

```js
var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);  // Note, your default calendarId is 'primary'
```

You would use the event resource with the [update semantics](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/update) to change the time for the event:

```js
function updateEventDateTime( calendarId, eventId, startDateTime, stopDateTime ) {
  // For update semantics, we need a complete event. Start by getting the event.
  var event = Calendar.Events.get(calendarId, eventId);

  // Change the event time
  event.start.dateTime = startDateTime.toISOString();
  event.stop.dateTime = stopDateTime.toISOString();

  // And update the event
  Calendar.Events.update(event, calendarId, eventId);
}
```

However, you don't really need a `getEventById()` method at all. By using the [patch semantics](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/patch) instead, you can jump immediately to setting the time, without needing to do a `get`. This will be more efficient:

```js
function updateEventDateTime( calendarId, eventId, startDateTime, stopDateTime ) {
  // For patch semantics, we only need to provide properties that are changing. Start with empty object.
  var event = {};

  // Change the event time
  event.start.dateTime = startDateTime.toISOString();
  event.stop.dateTime = stopDateTime.toISOString();

  // And update the event
  Calendar.Events.patch(event, calendarId, eventId);
}
```

If you're really concerned about having a `getEventById()` method, visit and star [Issue 4614](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4614).